# join the user voice channel with emoji react

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot and when the user react to a bot message, first it should check if the user is connected to a voice channel and if it is, the bot should join the voice channel, i'm using `awaitReactions` and it only returns reaction and user.

How can i get member voice channel with user or reaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to get a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/reply-prefix/class/GuildMember) from a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/reply-prefix/class/User), there are a few options.

- Use [`Guild#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/Guild?scrollTo=member). This function has already been removed in the `master` branch, and probably won't be included in future versions, but it's currently still very usable.

```js
const user = ...
const guild = ...
const member = guild.member(user);
```

- Get the member from [`GuildMemberManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache). If the member isn't in the cache you might have to use [`GuildMemberManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/GuildMemberManager)

```js
const user = ...
const guild = ...
const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
```

You can find the [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel) the member is in through their [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel). Every `VoiceState` has a [`channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) property referencing the voice channel they are currently in, or `null` if no channel was found.

```js
const member = ...
const channel = member.voice.channel;

if (channel) channel.join();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem is i don't know how to get `member` with reaction or user object, there are no guild or member in this objects

Comment: Thank you, i used `message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).voice.channel`, i need to get the guild by the message that i have set the `awaitReactions` for it.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted so it's easier to find for others in the future that share your problem.